# How to implement PDFKit ink annotation with UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit, pdfview

I created a PDFView. Now I just want to add an Ink annotation. So I override the `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, and `touchesEnded` methods and get the `UIBezierPath`. In `touchesEnded` I created a `PDFAnnotation` and add this `UIBezierPath`. Then I added this annotation to my `PDFView` current page. But I couldn't get the proper annotation. Annotation's bounds different from what I wrote.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    path = UIBezierPath()
    path?.lineWidth = 4.0

    let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
    path?.move(to: touch.location(in: self.pdfView))
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
{
    let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
    path?.addLine(to: touch.location(in: self.pdfView))
    self.pdfView.setNeedsDisplay()
    path?.stroke()
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let touch = touches.first
    path?.addLine(to: touch!.location(in: self.pdfView))
    self.pdfView.setNeedsDisplay()
    let annotation = PDFAnnotation(bounds: self.pdfView.bounds, forType: .ink, withProperties: nil)
    annotation.add(self.path!)
    if let currentPage = self.pdfView.currentPage
    {
        currentPage.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do this, create a subclass of PDFAnnotation and override `draw` func

```
import Foundation
import PDFKit

class PDFInkAnnotation: PDFAnnotation {
    var pathList: [UIBezierPath] = []

    public init(bounds: CGRect, paths: [UIBezierPath]) {
        pathList = paths
        super.init(bounds: bounds, forType: .ink, withProperties: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, in context: CGContext) {
        super.draw(with: box, in: context)
        
        UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
        context.saveGState()
        
        // Inverted coordinate system
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: bounds.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
        
        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
        context.setLineWidth(2.5)
        

        for path in pathList {
            context.addPath(path.cgPath)
            context.strokePath()
        }
        context.strokePath()
        
        context.restoreGState()
        UIGraphicsPopContext()
    }
}
```

And use:

```
private func addPathToPage(path: UIBezierPath) {
        if let page = pdfView?.currentPage {
            let bounds = page.bounds(for: pdfView!.displayBox)
            let inkAnnotation = PDFInkAnnotation(bounds: bounds, paths: [path])                                        
            page.addAnnotation(inkAnnotation)
        }
    }
```